# Difference between NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING and NF_INET_POST_ROUTING

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter

I couldn't find detail explain of these two flags. What I found is just a short description. Can anyone explain each flag and the difference between them? When is my hook function get called if I register with NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING or NF_INET_POST_ROUTING? From testing, I know tcphdr source and destination flips if I use one flag over the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This image](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png) and [this documentation](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html) should help a bit.

The `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` hook is called in the Network layer before the packet is passed to the internal routing engine, which determines whether to forward the packet on to another host or deliver it locally. Conversely, the `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING` hook is called after the routing engine has determined that a packet is destined for another host. Please note that the POST_ROUTING hook will be called both for packets that are forwarded in one interface and out the other as well as for packets from the local machine to an external host.

Comment: Thanks! that explains!